# Use xpath to find node by both attribute ID and text

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I understand how to find a node by attribute ID or by text, but unsure of the syntax to find by both. I'm using the XML library, I don't have access to `lxml` because can't install it on my work computer. Here's an excerpt of the XML I'm working with.

```
<product product-id="000100015BA00-00823">
    <ean/>
    <upc/>
    <page-attributes/>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="color">000100015BA00-00823</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
    <pinterest-enabled-flag>false</pinterest-enabled-flag>
    <facebook-enabled-flag>false</facebook-enabled-flag>
</product>
<product product-id="000100103H103-07546">
    <ean/>
    <upc/>
    <unit/>
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="color">000100103H103-07546</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
    <pinterest-enabled-flag>false</pinterest-enabled-flag>
</product>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
for x in  root.findall('dw:product/dw:custom-attributes/dw:custom-attribute[@attribute-id="color" and text()="000100103H103-07546"]', ns):
    print x.text
```

But I'm getting this error message: `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`

I think this is because `text()` doesn't work with the XML package. Is there a way to accomplish this without `lxml`?

Comment: The built-in module only supports a very limited set of XPath. I recommend you do `for x in root.findall('dw:product/dw:custom-attributes/dw:custom-attribute'):` and then do the attribute checks with a regular Python `if`.

Comment: Thank you! I actually am doing that as a workaround.  The problem is that it requires that I iterate through a very large file, so it's taking hours to complete if I have to check every chunk of XML with the if statement.

Comment: Use `.iterfind` instead of `.findall` and see if that helps. Also try `//dw:custom-attribute` instead of the complete path, since a shorter path means less checks. But the point is, finding nodes isn't magic. If you write an XPath one-liner to avoid writing a loop, that only means the loop you avoided runs inside the XPath implementation instead.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  Changed to .iterfind and it does seem to be running faster. Looks like it'll take about 2 hours, based on how fast it's completing each loop, which works for me.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: How big is the file (size/number of records)? Does it take 2 hours just to complete a full loop over the file doing no work, or to loop and do work? In the latter case you might want to look into parallel processing.

Comment: For extremely large XML files you should consider switching to a SAX parser (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.sax.html). It's not quite as convenient as a DOM parser, but it's *much* more resource effective as you can stream the file through the file. Definitely worth a try.

Comment: The XML file I'm parsing is about 900MB.  I put more thought into this, and realized my script was hugely inefficient.  It's pretty quick to parse through the entire file one time.  How I had written it originally was that I was looping through the entire file 1000+ times to match against another list. So now I'm parsing one time, and storing what I need in a CSV file for reference later. In the past I've tried this and have parsed through the file and stored the elements I need in a list (instead of writing to CSV). But that really slows down as it runs and takes forever. Always learning!

Comment: Also, thanks for the reference to SAX parser, I will look into this.  Sounds like it may be helpful for me.

Comment: SAX parsers definitely take considerable load out of the act of parsing huge XML files, especially when the XML is very regular (i.e. a long list of similar records). To look up things during your program's lifetime, use dicts. You can dump them to disk in JSON format if you want to keep them around. Building CSV works as well, but you need to do all the leg work yourself when writing/reading the file. JSON has *much* better handling characteristics.